# OptionParser python module - multiple entries of same variable?

Tags: python, shell, optionparser

I'm writing a little python script to get stats from several servers or a single server, and I'm using OptionParser to parse the command line input.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from optparse import OptionParser
...
parser.add_option("-s", "--server", dest="server", metavar="SERVER", type="string", 
                  help="server(s) to gather stats [default: localhost]")
...
```

my GOAL is to be able to do something like

```
#test.py -s server1 -s server2
```

and it would append both of those values within the options.server object in some way so that I could iterate through them, whether they have 1 value or 10.

Any thoughts / help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

```
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()
parser.add_option('-t', '--test', action='append')

options, args = parser.parse_args()
for i, opt in enumerate(options.test):
    print 'option %s: %s' % (i, opt)
```

Comment: That's what I thought would work, as well.
However I get this error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

when I give a string option that action.

Comment: @jduncan: Are you sure? I just tried it and again it works as expected.

Comment: This fails for me (Python 2.6) if I don't specify any options -- options.test is None and cannot be enumerated

Comment: Other than that, this code works with Python 2.4, 2.5 and 2.6

Comment: @jduncan: I can reproduce the error if I do `parser.add_option(..., default='a_string', action='append')`, but that is incorrect.  In fact, if you do that and not provide an option, you'll end up iterating over all the characters.  Plus, specifying anything would only append, so you could never override the default server.  Don't do it; if you need a default, do `enumerate(options.test or ['default'])`.

Comment: Re: iteration, setting default=[] in the add_option call makes it work with no options or multiple options.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done with optparse.

This is an example:

```
./test.py --categories=aaa --categories=bbb --categories ccc arg1 arg2 arg3
```

which prints:

```
arguments: ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
options: {'categories': ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']}
```

Full working example below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys
from optparse import OptionParser
from optparse import Option, OptionValueError

VERSION = '0.9.4'

class MultipleOption(Option):
    ACTIONS = Option.ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    STORE_ACTIONS = Option.STORE_ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    TYPED_ACTIONS = Option.TYPED_ACTIONS + ("extend",)
    ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS = Option.ALWAYS_TYPED_ACTIONS + ("extend",)

    def take_action(self, action, dest, opt, value, values, parser):
        if action == "extend":
            values.ensure_value(dest, []).append(value)
        else:
            Option.take_action(self, action, dest, opt, value, values, parser)


def main():
    PROG = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(__file__)[0])
    long_commands = ('categories')
    short_commands = {'cat':'categories'}
    description = """Just a test"""
    parser = OptionParser(option_class=MultipleOption,
                          usage='usage: %prog [OPTIONS] COMMAND [BLOG_FILE]',
                          version='%s %s' % (PROG, VERSION),
                          description=description)
    parser.add_option('-c', '--categories', 
                      action="extend", type="string",
                      dest='categories', 
                      metavar='CATEGORIES', 
                      help='comma separated list of post categories')

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        parser.parse_args(['--help'])

    OPTIONS, args = parser.parse_args()
    print "arguments:", args
    print "options:", OPTIONS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

More information at http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html#adding-new-actions

Answer (score 2):

You could try to check out [argparse](http://code.google.com/p/argparse/). It provides "nargs" parameter meaning you would be able to do something along

```
#test.py -s server1 server2
```

I know that's not exactly what requested but it might be a decent compromise without too much hassle. :)

Answer (score 2):

Could be easier to accept a comma-separated list of servers:

```
# test.py -s server1,server2
```

and split the value within your script.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a known working example (from http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html):

```
parser.add_option('-r', '--recipient',
                  type='string', action='append', metavar='RECIPIENT',
                  default=[], dest='recipients',
                  help='A To: header value (at least one required)')
```

I think the usages is something like:

```
python script.py -r some@where.com -r no@where.com -r any@where.com
```

Comment: The answer is for argparser, not the question optparser.